# Making text in text mesh stay for few seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to display my text for 3 seconds, so I did the following, but it is just blinking and disappearing.

```
  void Start () {
        Invoke("ShowInfoText", 2f);
    }

void ShowInfoText()
{
    infoText.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    infoText.text = "Welocme!";

    Invoke("DisableInfoText", 5f);
}

void DisableInfoText()
{
    infoText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

How do I make the text to stay for 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `InvokeRepeating`.

> public void InvokeRepeating(string methodName, float time, float
>   **repeatRate**);

You could also use a Coroutine:

```
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(DoTextShow());
}

IEnumerator DoTextShow()
{
    infoText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    infoText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    infoText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: This will disable the text all together after 3 seconds

Comment: @Coder221 I'm confused, what did you want to happen after 3 seconds?

Comment: That is just a welcome text, which I want to be displayed initially for 3 seconds. I want the text to be displayed after 2 seconds for 3 seconds when the game starts. I also have various texts which are displayed throughout the game. The problem with your code is that it is disabling all the texts in the game after 3 seconds.

Comment: @Coder221 I've modified the answer, you can all as many yields as you like.